# Edmx designer and item template missing from VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, edmx

I am nearly sure this was available and working before, but at this site I have a very recent upgrade from VS2010 to VS2012. I find that if I double click an .edmx file, it by default opens in an XML editor. Also, the Enterprise Data Model item template is missing, so I must open the project in VS2010 just to add a new data model. Are there any known issues that could cause this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to select the **Microsoft Web Developer Tools** in the VS2012 setup to get EF back. Now I have the designer.

*// Edit*
Selecting **Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools** also installs the EF Designer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to open EF items. Note that I had installed Entity Framework using Nuget Package Manager earlier. I am able to see a lot of Item Templates in the 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Data' Directory.

Is that present on the system where you are having the trouble?