# ADO.NET Data Model Missing Templates From VS 2013

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, ado.net

I am trying to do some SQL stuff with Entity Framework, using Visual Studio 2013 and C#.

My issue is that I am missing sevral templates from the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" item in the template panel of my visual studio.

This is what I have :
[image]

And this is what I should get :
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.
*I tried installing the latest version of the entity framework from NuGet, but it did not solve my issue

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was not helping.

Comment: make sure you have selected "Web" or Database Tools in VS2013 setup: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13247029/1466046